# How to add space between two tags vertically(P.S My margin -top is not working)

Tags: html, css

I was Building a website where I encountered a problem that my h1 content is overlapping with my navigation bar. I have used margin-top tag in css and its not working.

```
<div class="main">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_resize">
      <div class="menu_nav">

        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Voicecom</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Marketing Sevices</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">IT Management Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Employement Opportunities </a> </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>

      <div class="logo"><h1><a href="index.html"><span>Voicecom </span> Technologies<br /><small>Communications Any Time Any Where</small></a></h1></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hbg">
    <div class="hbg_resize">
      <img src="images/hbg_img.jpg" width="334" height="223" alt="img" class="hbgimg" />
      <h2>Read me first...</h2>
      <p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna a turpis ornare aliquam id hendrerit nisl.</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna a turpis ornare aliquam id hendrerit nisl. Pellentesque adipiscing blandit mollis. Curabitur varius est et sem rhoncus et pretium massa molestie.</p>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/readmore.jpg" width="115" height="33" alt="read more" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS File

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   color: #5f5f5f;
   font: normal 12px/1.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html,
.main {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.clr {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

h1 {
    margin: -32px 0 0 0;
    padding: 24px 0;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font: bold 22px/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 a,
h1 a:hover {
    color: #D88100;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 span {
    color: #ffa800;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 2000px;
}

h1 small {
    font: normal 13px/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font: bold 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #a3ce67;
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin: 8px 0;
}

p {
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding: 0 0 8px 0;
    font: normal 12px/1.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #5e8525;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Please Do let me know if someone want more of the code, I have hereby attached only part of it.
Please Help!!!!

Comment: Some more code or a jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: I havent use jsfiddle anything else you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wants the h1 to go lower on the page, then you would have to remove the *span* in the css. So it's going to be something like this:

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   color: #5f5f5f;
   font: normal 12px/1.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html,
.main {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.clr {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

h1 {
    padding: 24px 0;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font: bold 22px/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 a,
h1 a:hover {
    color: #D88100;
    text-decoration: none;
}


h1 small {
    font: normal 13px/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font: bold 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #a3ce67;
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin: 8px 0;
}

p {
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding: 0 0 8px 0;
    font: normal 12px/1.8em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #5e8525;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_resize">
      <div class="menu_nav">

        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Voicecom</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Marketing Sevices</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">IT Management Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Employement Opportunities </a> </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>

      <div class="logo"><h1><a href="index.html"><span>Voicecom </span> Technologies<br /><small>Communications Any Time Any Where</small></a></h1></div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hbg">
    <div class="hbg_resize">
      <img src="images/hbg_img.jpg" width="334" height="223" alt="img" class="hbgimg" />
      <h2>Read me first...</h2>
      <p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna a turpis ornare aliquam id hendrerit nisl.</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac magna a turpis ornare aliquam id hendrerit nisl. Pellentesque adipiscing blandit mollis. Curabitur varius est et sem rhoncus et pretium massa molestie.</p>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/readmore.jpg" width="115" height="33" alt="read more" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your Code perfectly Works ThankYou So much!!!!
Can you tell me the reason why you had removed the span class?

Comment: I'm glad to hear, then mark it as the correct answer, so it can be closed :) The span is not a class, it's a tag. If you want the span, then you just need to do this: 

CSS:
h1, span  {
    color: #ffa800;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}